# Is there a second coming of Jesus in Islam?

Tags: prophet-isa, day-of-judgement

So AFAIK the orthodox Muslim belief is that Jesus will return and lead the war against Dajjal when end times are near.

However, I've troubles in believing in this due to two reasons.

- It is not mentioned in the Qur'an at all. It seems weird to me that God will leave out such an important information out of His book.
- In [Qur'an 7:137](http://quran.com/7/187) God says:

> They ask you, [O Muhammad], about the Hour: when is its arrival? Say, "Its knowledge is only with my Lord. None will reveal its time except Him. It lays heavily upon the heavens and the earth. It will not come upon you except unexpectedly." They ask you as if you are familiar with it. Say, "Its knowledge is only with Allah , but most of the people do not know."

For me, this verse clearly says that the Qiyamah will come unexpectedly. Now how is that compatible with the 2nd coming of the Jesus ? If it's a sign of the Last Hour, then the Last Hour is not that unexpected right? I've even heard some Muslims say that the Qiyamah will happen after 40 years of Jesus' 2nd coming.

It seems plausible to me that this belief has came into Islam from the Christians that early Muslims have interacted. Though, I might be wrong.

In short, what are the opinions regarding second coming of Jesus in Islam ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evidence for the return of Jesus from the Quran](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/45916/evidence-for-the-return-of-jesus-from-the-quran)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a belief second coming of Jesus عليه السلام in Islam.

The belief not being based in the Quran is debatable, as many see it in  [43:61](https://quran.com/43/61) , [4:159](https://quran.com/4/159) , [3:46](https://quran.com/3/46) etc. This should already have been covered in other answers on the site and elsewhere.

It is also proven from a number of ahadith narrated from several sahabah through various chains of transmission, reaching *tawatur*. Over seventy five ahadith have been collected in the book [التصريح بما تواتر في نزول المسيح](https://shamela.ws/book/8575/2).

> والذي نفسي بيده، ليوشكن أن ينزل فيكم ابن مريم حكما عدلا
>
> By Him in Whose Hands my soul is, son of Mary (Jesus) will shortly descend amongst you people (Muslims) as a just ruler
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/60/118)</sup>

There being signs of Qiyamah is not contrary to it being sudden, what is meant by unexpected is that no one knows its exact time and that they will be hit unawares.

If you are going to deny prophecies just because of the suddenness of Qiyamah then you would need to deny much of the Quran.

- Allah has promised to the believers victories and dominance ( [24:55](https://quran.com/24/55), [48:16](https://quran.com/48/16) etc.)
- Allah has foretold of the release *Gog and Magog* before the hour ([18:99](https://quran.com/18/99), [21:96](https://quran.com/21/96))
- Allah has foretold of the emergence of the *Beast of the Earth* before the hour ( [27:82](https://quran.com/27/82) )

Would you say that these verse are false since they are events that will occur before Qiyamah and presumably Qiyamah will not occur until these events pass?

```
In short, what are the opinions regarding second coming of Jesus in Islam ?
```

The Ahl al-Sunnah and also Shia affirm the belief. It can be found in books documenting Muslim aqeedah such as:

> ونؤمن بأشراط الساعة: من ... ونزول عيسى ابن مريم عليه السلام من السماء
>
> We believe in the signs of the Hour such as ... the descent of Jesus son of Mary, peace be upon him, from heaven
>
> <sup>— [Aqeedah al-Tahhaawiyyah](https://shamela.ws/book/10549/499#p1)</sup>

The belief that there won't be a second coming is uncommon and considered heretical. It has been held by minority groups such some of the Mu'tazilah and Jahmiyyah (see [إكمال المعلم بفوائد مسلم](https://shamela.ws/book/122406/4925#p7) ) and presently by the Ahmadiyyah and other individuals. Note that some scholars consider denial of Jesus's return as basis enough for takfir.

Comment: Good answers. Thanks. Could you expand it by explaining why some groups do not believe in the second coming of Jesus ? For example, why Mu'tazilah does not believe in it? I cannot read the links you put as I don't know Arabic myself.

Comment: @SpiderRico, Ask a new question on that

Answer (score 0):

ALL classical Mu’tazilite scholars believed in the return of Jesus pbuh. They also believed that the wall of Dhul Qarnayn is yet to fall, and they believed Dhul Qarnayn in the Qur’an was Alexander the Great, and this is evident from the story of the Mu’tazilite Caliph Al-Wathiq when he had that terrifying dream about Gog and Magog. The story is also narrated by Al-Tusi. As for Zamakshari, he wasn’t a classical Mu’tazilite and yet he also believed in the return of Jesus pbuh.