# On what basis do some Muslims not believe in the second coming of Jesus?

Tags: prophet-isa, day-of-judgement, mutazilites

This a follow-up on [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/62733/is-there-a-second-coming-of-jesus-in-islam/62740#62740).

In the accepted answer of the linked question, author notes some Muslim groups, such as Mu'tazilah, didn't believe in the second coming of Jesus.

I'd like to know that, on what basis did these groups not believe in the second coming of Jesus.

Comment: Maybe the strongest evidence is in [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40428/how-can-prophet-isa-return-to-earth-without-violating-prophet-muhammad-being-the?rq=1).

Comment: I'm a bit confused so far I considered az-Zamakhshari from among the Mu'tazilah, but at this point he agrees with the majority of scholars in his al-Kashaaf. After reading a bit more about this sect i found out that there are different groups, this may mean not all of them agree about this topic. As it is not part of their common creed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly note that my answer says that "some" of the Mu'tazilah held that opinion. It is not *the* opinion of Mu'tazilah as a whole. As @Medi1Saif has noted in the comments, Zamakhshari in his [tafsir](https://al-maktaba.org/book/23627/1993#p1) has rebutted the arguments of those who held the contrary belief.

Their evidence (as mentioned in e.g. [إكمال المعلم بفوائد مسلم](https://al-maktaba.org/book/32843/5078#p7) and [شرح النووي على مسلم](https://al-maktaba.org/book/1711/3997#p1)) is that they have relied upon the Prophet Muhammad ﷺ being the last of the Prophets:

> وخاتم النبيين
>
> [Muhammad is the] last of the prophets
>
> <sup>— [Quran 33:40](http://quran.com/33/40)</sup>

> لا نبي بعدي
>
> There will be no prophet after me
>
> <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/44/48)</sup>

Their argument being that if it is accepted that Jesus عليه السلام is sent back, then he would be the last prophet not Muhammad ﷺ.

The response to that is that the meaning of being the last prophet is that he is the last one to whom prophethood was granted. Jesus's prophethood and ministry came before Muhammad, and his second coming is not in the role of a prophet or to give new revelation, but rather as a caliph to implement the shariah of Muhammad ﷺ.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: Before giving a second answer with almost the same content I'd like to point at the verse ([3:81](https://legacy.quran.com/3/81)) that shows the covenant of the prophets and their agreement to follow the upcoming prophet which underlines that 'Isa would have to follow Muhammad if he was appointed after him.